# Connect to local HBase

Tags: scala, ubuntu, hbase

### Hi all

I tried to develop Scala application which will works with HBase and face with one strange issue.

#### My environment:

```
Workstation - Ubuntu 14.04 x64
Java - Oracle JDK 1.7
```

System variables:
**~/.bashsr file:**

```
export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/scala/scala-2.10.5
export PATH=$SCALA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export HBASE_HOME=/usr/local/hbase-0.94.18
export HBASE_CONF=/usr/local/hbase-0.94.18/conf
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HBASE_HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark-1.3.1-hd2.4
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
```

For my application I downloaded and install HBase 0.94.18 (equals version of HBase from AWS EMR 3.9.0 AMI). 
HBase configuration files:
1. $HBASE_HOME/conf/hbase-env.sh contains next settings

```
export HBASE_LOG_DIR=/home/yustas/hbase/logs
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
export HBASE_OPTS="-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.security.krb5.realm= -Djava.security.krb5.kdc="
```

2. $HBASE_HOME/conf/hbase-site.xml

   ```
   <configuration>
    <property>
     <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
     <value>file:///home/yustas/hbase/data</value>
    </property>
    <property>
     <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
     <value>/home/yustas/hbase/zookeeper</value>
    </property>
    <property>
     <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
     <value>false</value>
   </property>
   </configuration>
   ```

I can start end stop my local HBase by commands:

```
start-hbase.sh
stop-hbase.sh
```

Also, I can open shell by hbase shell and create a table and put some data in this table.
I can see my HBase status by Web UI: http://localhost:60010/master-status

#### Scala program

I have copy of **hbase-site.xml** file in *{PROJECT}/src/main/resource* folder and use it as resource.
I try to run very sipmle code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{HTableDescriptor, HColumnDescriptor, HBaseConfiguration}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{HTable, HBaseAdmin}

object DataLoad {
  var tableName: String = "table"
  var tableCF : String = "field_set"
  var hbaseAdmin: HBaseAdmin = null

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    hbaseAdmin = new HBaseAdmin(conf)  //program stops responding in this line, and just hanging out.
    if(!hbaseAdmin.tableExists(tableName)){
      val tdesc = new HTableDescriptor(tableName)
      tdesc.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor(tableCF));
      hbaseAdmin.createTable(tdesc)
    }
    println("HBase: table " + tableName + " available state is " + hbaseAdmin.isTableAvailable(tableName))
  }
}
```

**ISSUE**

My code was compiled and run successfully but in line **hbaseAdmin = new HBaseAdmin(conf)** program stops responding in this line and just hanging out. I waiting ~ 5 min - no changes.

I would like to know where I have got a bug? I can't find this issue in this and other specific sites today.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set this properties too in the hbase-site.xml

```
<property>
 <name>hbase.master</name>
 <value>localhosts:60000</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
 <value>localhost</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
 <value>2181</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Thank Marco, but your hbase-site.xml not helped me

Answer (score 0):

check your hbase is running like ;

`ps -ef | grep hbase`, if hbase is not running, execute

```
$HBASE_HOME/bin/start-hbase.sh
```

probably, hbase is not running